Restringir campo de texto con tres números antes y tres números después de punto decimal
necesito restringir en un input de tipo text que solo se puedan ingresar números decimales,separados por punto y que solo permita ingresar tres números antes del punto decimal y tres después del punto decimal,la función que tengo ahorita es la siguiente,restringe después del punto decimal solamente:
function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    var number = el.value.split('.');

    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
       return false;
    }
      //just one dot
    if(number.length>1 && charCode == 46){
       return false;
    }
      //get the carat position
    var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
    var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");

    if( caratPos > dotPos && dotPos>-1 && (number[1].length > 1)){
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
    
  //thanks: http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/
function getSelectionStart(o) {
    if (o.createTextRange) {
       var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
       r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
       if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
       return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
    }
    else return o.selectionStart
}

Gracias.

Validar la entrada mediante la presión de una tecla funciona salvo hagas un copy/pase. Por este motivo yo prefiero utilizar el evento input, lamentablemente este evento se ejecuta después del ingreso por lo que no es posible cancelar cuando la situación marca una entrada no valida.
Para solventar esto, podemos añadir un evento beforeinput que se ejecuta antes, el cual se encargará solo de guardar el valor antiguo. Luego en el evento input si no pasa la validación, reestablecemos el valor al valor antiguo previamente guardado
Y para la validación es simple, solo tenemos 3 casos:

Cuando es vacio, aqui no hacemos nada
Cuando el valor es NaN (no es un número) reestablecemos el valor antiguo
Hacemos un split y validamos el largo de cada parte no supere el 3 de largo.
En cualquier otro caso, pasa la validación



const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener("beforeinput",  e => e.target.oldValue = e.target.value);
input.addEventListener("input", validarNumero);


function validarNumero(e) {
  if(e.target.value.length === 0)
    return

  if(isNaN(e.target.value))
    e.target.value = e.target.oldValue 
  
  const parts = e.target.value.split(".");
  if(parts[0].length > 3 || parts.at(1)?.length > 3)
    e.target.value = e.target.oldValue 
}
<input>




Con más inputs:


document.querySelectorAll(".solonumero").forEach(input => {        
 input.addEventListener("beforeinput",  e => e.target.oldValue =e.target.value);
 input.addEventListener("input", validarNumero); 
});

function validarNumero(e) {
  if(e.target.value.length === 0)
    return

  if(isNaN(e.target.value))
    e.target.value = e.target.oldValue 
  
  const parts = e.target.value.split(".");
  if(parts[0].length > 3 || parts.at(1)?.length > 3)
    e.target.value = e.target.oldValue 
}
<input class="solonumero">
<input class="solonumero">
<input class="solonumero">
<input class="solonumero">




muchas gracias,justo lo que necesitaba.@Yussef

,mira ahora tengo otro inconveniente,cómo hago para poder aplicar esta solución a múltiples campos ? lo que hice fue usar document.getElementById porque querySelector me tira el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

@Samael (1) a cada input le agregas una clase, digamos que se llama solonumero (2) luego las primeras 3 líneas del código de la respuesta la reemplazas por: document.querySelectorAll(".solonumero").forEach(input => {      input.addEventListener("beforeinput",  e => e.target.oldValue = e.target.value);     input.addEventListener("input", validarNumero); });   https://i.sstatic.net/7oNrCxhe.png

Funciona solo en el primer input con clase "solonumero",en los restantes solo permite digitar los 3 primeros números @Yussef

@Samael He actualizado la respuesta y al final de la misma he colocado el código que te indico, y creo que funciona correctamente ¿o también vez el mismo error?

Disculpa,cometí un tremendo error,no recuerdo en qué momento le puse maxlength ="3" a varios campos,por eso no servía,en realidad funciona de maravilla,muchas gracias @Yussef

@Samael Ahh que bueno, cuanto me alegro. Saludos y suerte con el proyecto

Muchas gracias de nuevo,bendiciones, @Yussef

Saludos,mira y cómo podría establecer valores mínimo y máximo para estos campos de texto?,en unos casos deben estar entre 00.00 y 99.99 y otros entre 000.000 y 999.999,sé que con campos de tipo number es sencillo pero quería saber si se puede aplicar sobre un input de tipo text como en este caso, @Yussef.



function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var value = el.value;
    var cursorPos = el.selectionStart;

 
    if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46 && charCode > 31) {
        return false;
    }

     if (charCode == 46 && value.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        return false;
    }

     if (value.indexOf('.') == -1 && value.length >= 3 && charCode != 46) {
        return false;
    }

     var dotPosition = value.indexOf('.');
    if (dotPosition != -1 && cursorPos > dotPosition && value.substring(dotPosition + 1).length >= 3) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validateFloatKeyPress(this, event)" />



El código que disponibilizou no verificaba el límite de dígitos antes y después del punto decimal. Ahora implementando la corrección, el código restringe la entrada a números (48-57) y punto decimal, usa indexOf para localizar el punto, substring para capturar los dígitos después del punto y length para limitar a 3 dígitos antes y 3 después del punto decimal.

Gracias por tu ayuda,bendiciones @cardosource
